# Jenkins polled repository once then never again, though 1 minute interval is set

Tags: jenkins

I've set up a Jenkins job and set the poll interval at 1 minute (I used this syntax 0 * * * *).

Looking in the Polling log I can see its reported that a poll call was made as soon as I saved the changes to the job.
But not over 10 minutes later it hasn't made any other polls.

Any suggestions how I can proceed determining the problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000251/how-schedule-build-in-jenkins and http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Schedules-td1589819.html (shows syntax for "once every period" via `i/x` field syntax)

Comment: I initially tried * * * * * for every minute, but Jenkins threw up a warning message saying "did you mean 0 * * * *"

Comment: See the second link provided and the `i/x` syntax (interval/period). It gives (at least) examples of `*/15` and `1-6/2`. The link also explains why "5 * * * *" only runs 5 minutes after the hour. Consider self-answering with the applicable problem and solution when the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for "* * * * *".

Jenkins gives a warning since every minute can be a bit excessive, but your version control server shouldn't have any problems handling the load.

Answer (score -1):

Your cron syntax is set to poll once per hour, at zero minutes past the hour.  From the Jenkins help text:

This field follows the syntax of cron (with minor differences). Specifically, each line consists of 5 fields separated by TAB or whitespace:

MINUTE HOUR DOM MONTH DOW

MINUTE  Minutes within the hour (0-59)

HOUR    The hour of the day (0-23)

DOM The day of the month (1-31)

MONTH   The month (1-12)

DOW The day of the week (0-7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday.

Comment: Well, "yes", but this doesn't explain how to run such a job every minute and, as an *incomplete excerpt with no reference link*, seems to hint it is not possible (while it is very much supported).

Comment: Fair enough - you should put your comments above into an answer, I would upvote it.