# Automated Build War in Grails project

Tags: grails, jenkins, automation, war

I have my project with Grails on GGTS.

How best can I include automatic ( say weekly build ) build of WAR on a periodic basic.
Any plugins out there?

Comment: Added Jenkins tag for more visibility but question may not be limited to Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

A CI tool like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) is your best bet you can set up a job to build as often as you like and you can even have jenkins store the wars for you. Using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to automate this process.
Here are some links from stackoverflow that may help you:
[How to schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins) /
[How schedule build in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000251/how-schedule-build-in-jenkins) .