# Test cases in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testcase

Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but can I run a project in jenkins that is not a test project?

I only need to run it at a specific hour and after it runs I want to receive a log file from the project.

Comment: Yes. You can take a look at these related questions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000251/how-schedule-build-in-jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can run lots of different types of projects using Jenkins. In your job configuration, you can check the box "Build periodically" or "Poll SCM" so you can specify build start time using a cron expression. While "Build periodically" will simply start your build at the specified time, "Poll SCM" will only start a new build if there is new commits in your SCM.

If you want to receive a specific log file that is generated during your build, you could configure "Archive the Artifacts" under the Post-Build Actions section of your configuration and then specify the name of the file to be kept. You could easily access your archived files afterward through the link:

```
http://[yourJenkins]/job/[jobName]/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/[artifactName]
```

But if you need to send this file somewhere else, you could use the SCP Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCP+plugin).