# How to schedule job in Jenkins at particular timings

Tags: jenkins, scheduling

I want to schedule Jenkins jobs at three specific times (viz. 5 AM, 1 PM, 5 PM). What is the expression to do that?

Regards
Manish Mehra

Comment: may be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000251/how-schedule-build-in-jenkins

Comment: Yuri gave you the good answer, you should use: H 5,13,17 * * * to schedule your job at 5am, 1pm and 5pm

Comment: Thanks Yuri and Bruno. If I wanted to schedule it at 5:30, 13:30 and 17:30, how should I have done that? I tried doing  H 5:30,13:30,17:30 * * *. That gave me error.

Answer (score 1):

you can use expression like : **0 5,13,17 * * ***
Please refer to [Cron Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Format) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Use below expression if you want to schedule it at 5:30, 13:30 and 17:30

**30 5,13,17 * * ***