# Running Jenkins on Remote Machine on a specific time ..how?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have few Selenium Java Projects that I wanted to run through Jenkins on a specific time.

I run Jenkins from a remote desktop machine and I start it using command prompt for creating a project / build using

`java -jar jenkins.war`

and access Jenkins using localhost.

If I wanted to run my projects every day at 6 AM,

1. Should I have my Virtual Machine where my Jenkins is residing on?
2. Should Jenkins be running all the time?
3. Will Jenkins automatically run the build even if it is not running on the Virtual Machine if I make the Build selecting "Run Periodically"?

Please suggest me possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Best possible solution is thru Docker+jenkins

Have your dockerfile ready with Run command and steps, which can be done by pulling image in container with necessary config and files and combine with Jenkins server as well, once the run is complete it cleans up the container and it is easy to maintain. All you need is to play with docker to achieve the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question complete. Maybe you should improve it a bit.

You access a VM via remote desktop. On this VM you have a jenkins server running. I assume your VM is running 24/7. So no need to ever stop jenkins. And how you confiure your time, you'll find in this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000251/how-schedule-build-in-jenkins).